# Application Launch Error when trying to launch Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Have  tried to launch Python 3.6 in the latest version of Anaconda (Anaconda 2019.10). This was to download the Tensorflow and Keras packages. I have installed them from the packages installment page and it seems like they installed successfully, but when I try to finally launch Jupiter Notebook in this environment, I get the following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\andre_000\Anaconda3\envs\snakes\Scripts\jupyter-notebook->script.py", line 6, in 
>   from notebook.notebookapp import main
>   File "C:\Users\andre_000\Anaconda3\envs\snakes\lib\site->packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 49, in 
>   from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
>   File "C:\Users\andre_000\Anaconda3\envs\snakes\lib\site->packages\zmq\eventloop__init__.py", line 3, in 
>   from zmq.eventloop.ioloop import IOLoop
>   File "C:\Users\andre_000\Anaconda3\envs\snakes\lib\site->packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 78, in 
>   while _IOLoop.configurable_default() is not _IOLoop:
>   File "C:\Users\andre_000\Anaconda3\envs\snakes\lib\site->packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 328, in configurable_default
>   from tornado.platform.asyncio import AsyncIOLoop
>   File "C:\Users\andre_000\Anaconda3\envs\snakes\lib\site->packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 34, in 
>   asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
>   AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute >'WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy'

Is there anything I could do about this, been trying to install Tensorflow and their related packages in the anaconda environment for a few days. Proving to be very difficult.

Comment: Can you show how you installed them, and some info on the environment (i.e `conda list`)?

Comment: Must add that I am using windows 8

Comment: @AMC  Downloaded the latest anaconda version(2019.10). On the Environment tab using the base root environment (originally 3.7)  went to cmd,                             
 conda install python=3.6. Activating environment giving it a new name.  On the main environment tab on anaconda  going to unstalled and installing the packages. Then finally trying to load Jupiter notebook, in this new environment that is when I get the error.

Comment: _On the Environment tab using the base root environment_ Don't use the base environment. The advice I usually give for these kinds of issues is to remove all trace of Anaconda/Conda on your computer, and start over from scratch.